# How to add or replace an element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to apply config transformations. I want to add an element if it does not exist, or overwrite it if it does exist.

Desired result:

```
<foo>
    <bar value="baz" />        
</foo>
```

What template can I use to have this output for both inputs

```
<foo>
    <bar value="123" />        
</foo>
```

and

```
<foo>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo/bar/@value[.='123']">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">baz</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo[not(bar)]">
  <foo>
    <bar value="baz"/>
  </foo>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the first provided XML document**:

```
<foo>
    <bar value="123" />
</foo>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<foo>
   <bar value="baz"/>
</foo>
```

**When applied on the second provided XML document:**

```
<foo>
</foo>
```

**it also produces the same correct result**.

**Explanation**: Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: is there a way to make this a bit more general? The element i'm adding is a bit more complex than the example. How would I replace an element containing sub-elements, not based on an attribute but based on element name?

Comment: @MelGerats: Everything is possible. Please, try to define this well and ask as a new question. I'll be glad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .NET? If so you can consider something especially made for these config transformation. The MS employee Sayed Ibrahim Hashim created [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) which is web config transforms for all VS projects.

Your 2 scenarios then become:

```
<foo>
  <bar xdt:Transform="Replace" value="123" />
</foo>

<foo xdt:Transform="Replace">
</foo>
```

Xslt a bit verbose IMO. The Hansleman has a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) on it

Documentation about the different transformations can be found here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134

The SlowCheetah extension adds a target which you can copy to the project to make it self contained

On Codeplex there is also a simple project if you want to use it as an exe or do it in code called [Transform Config](http://transformconfig.codeplex.com).

PS. Tom van Orbit One hier ;)

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately I have no control over how the actual transformations are done